# How to Create C# Linq Query

Tags: linq

I have class like bellow

```
class ParentModel
{
   List<DomHtml> SearchHtml{get;set;}
   List<DomHtml> SortHtml{get;set;}
}

class DomHtml{

}
```

From `ParentModel` I want to merge `SortHtml` and `SearchHtml` to create a single `List<DomHtml>` using a LINQ query.

I have method like below. I want to remove all if condition with a LINQ query.

```
public string ReadDataTableDom(IDTFeatureAttribute dataTableAttribute)
{
    string dom = string.Empty;
    List<IDTDomCreatorService> collection = new List<IDTDomCreatorService>();

    if (dataTableAttribute.SearchAttribute != null && dataTableAttribute.SearchAttribute.dtDomAttribute != null)
    {
        collection.AddRange(dataTableAttribute.SearchAttribute.dtDomAttribute);
    }

    if (dataTableAttribute.Paging != null && dataTableAttribute.Paging.dtDomAttribute != null)
    {
        collection.AddRange(dataTableAttribute.Paging.dtDomAttribute);
    }

    if (dataTableAttribute.AjaxSourceDataAttribute != null && dataTableAttribute.AjaxSourceDataAttribute.dtDomAttribute != null)
    {
        collection.AddRange(dataTableAttribute.AjaxSourceDataAttribute.dtDomAttribute);
    }
    return domHtmlReaderService.GetDomHtml(collection.AsEnumerable());
}
```

Comment: So `SearchHtml.Concat(SortHtml)` perhaps? Or `SearchHtml.Union(SortHtml)`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot mention one thing, Before do that we need to check SearchHtml and SortHtml null or not and the ParentModel model not only have SortHtml and SearchHtml . it have more than List<DomHtml> like paging, Add, update,delete ...

Comment: Sorry, that comment made very little sense to me, but you should be able to do that... please show what you've tried and what happened, ideally with a [mcve], bearing in mind my hint of using `SortHtml` and `SearchHtml`.

Comment: I update the question with example

Comment: That's far from a *complete* example, and it's not minimal either. There's no obvious relationship between the class declarations you've shown and the later code...